# Why can a commerce catalog not be shared between multiple websites

Tags: sitecore-commerce, commerce-catalog

In a Sitecore Commerce solution, why can a Commerce catalog not be shared between multiple websites?

Say I have two websites selling the same set of products in the same languages, but requiring some other country-specific content on the front-end, what would be the best way to manage that?

(Sorry, I realise that that is a separate question, but it is quite closely related to the first, so hopefully is allowed?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiple sites cannot share the same catalog in Sitecore as the catalog will only be indexed in one location and the other sites will not recognize catalog content outside their own site area. You can use a Postman script to clone an existing catalog if you want the same products on multiple storefronts.

https://doc.sitecore.com/users/91/sitecore-experience-commerce/en/set-up-a-catalog-for-a-storefront-site.html