# Seeking suggestion on managing global product catalog with single site in SXC-9.0.1

Tags: sitecore-commerce, commerce-catalog

We are implementing a global product catalog to support different catalogs with different currencies and prices. We currently have a single site globally. The true source for catalog is SAP ERP system, and we want to get all catalog info (with different currencies, prices, etc) using minion and store it on `Sitecore commerce`.

As I am aware of SXC a site will support a single catalog. Since we have to store `country/salesorg` specific products, what would be your recommendation `approach/structure` of the catalog to be maintained in this case?

If we store everything into one catalog, it would be a time-consuming process to filter the products based on geolocation!

Comment: I don't think right now Sitecore support sharing of catalogs, you can see this - https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/23884/why-can-a-commerce-catalog-not-be-shared-between-multiple-websites

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We implemented similar solution with 5 catalogs living in the same site, sharing most of the products with the possibility to have exclusive products.
This is what we did:
-From GeoIP resolve Language
-In Sitecore create a versionde catalog configuration that will map language to appropriate catalog.

Hope that helps.